# Get time between using the phone

Tags: swift, user-controls

I try to make an app which can assume the sleeping time of the user.

Samsung devices (samsung health) can assume the sleeping period based on yesterday last, and today first interaction. The app no needs to run into background. So I think, that it reads somehow from the relevant device data.

Is there any way to get the time when the user uses his/her phone in Swift?

Comment: It depends on the user. Some people have their phones in their hands nearly every waking hour.

Comment: You'd have to use the Health APIs available to see the sleep data the user has tracked. That data could come from any source the user wants to track it, like using the Bedtime feature in the Clock app, or using a sleep tracker like Pillow.